# MSVC nmake: Is there an elegent approach to check headers modification without creating extra files and specifying source files?

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, nmake

Current version as follows:

```
main.exe: *.c resource.res
    $(MAKE) $(**:.c=.obj)
    link $(**:.c=.obj) /OUT:$@
```

Recursive make and inference rule make specifying the source code list unnecessary, which is convenient.

Is it possible to improve this makefile, so that it can monitor the header files' changes?

It would be great if the new version:

1. Does not create extra files.
2. Still not require specifying the source code list. This should be hard without inference rule.

Comment: Have all .objs depend on all headers. Not very elegant though...

Comment: @Andreas Seems that's the only approach, thank you! Will you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?